# Add color scale to matplotlib colorbar according to RGBA image channels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to plot a RGBA image with a colorbar representing color values.

The RGBA image is generated from raw data, transforming the 2d data array into a 6d-array with x, y, [R, G, B and A] according to the color input. E.g. 'green' will make it fill just the G channel with the values from the 2d-array, leaving R and B = 0 and A = 255. Like this:

[image: data_to_color_equation]

All solutions I found would apply a color map or limit the vmin and vmax of the colorbar but what I need is a colorbar that goes from pitch black to the brightest color present in the image. E.g. if I have an image in shades of purple, the color bar should go from 0 to 'full' purple with only shades of purple in it. The closest solution I found was this (https://pelson.github.io/2013/working_with_colors_in_matplotlib/), but it doesn't fit a "general" solution. 
An image I'm getting is given below.

[image: color_data_plot]

```
import numpy as np
from ImgMath import colorize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Mapping

data = Mapping.getpeakmap('Au')
# data shape is (10,13) and len(data) is 10

norm_data = data/data.max()*255
color_data = colorize(norm_data,'green')
# color_data shape is (10,13,4) and len(color_data) is 10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = plt.imshow(color_data)
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is quite long, and honestly I'm not sure what your exact problem is. Although the brought scope is usually very interesting, this site is really only about the specific programming problem you encounter. Try to strip you question down to these essentials. Also make sure that your example is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I tried to reduce the question and make it more coding-oriented in the last edit.

Comment: This is already better, but still not reproducible. Try to get rid of `ImgMath` and `Mapping` which are non-standard. You can use some fictitious data instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map your data with a custom, all-green, colormap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# input 2D array
data = np.random.randint(0,255, size=(10,13))

z = np.zeros(256)
colors = np.linspace(0,1,256)
alpha = np.ones(256)

#create colormap
greencolors = np.c_[z,colors,z,alpha]
cmap = ListedColormap(greencolors)


im = plt.imshow(data/255., cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and I managed to create other color maps as well fitting perfectly my needs for the time being.